# I have rewriten all my questions that I was told were sub-standard and I'm still question banned

Tags: support, post-ban

I have rewritten all the questions that I was told were not within Stack Overflow quality standards, and I'm still question banned. Should I rewrite them again?

Am I missing something? Does anyone know what I should do now?

I tried to write good questions but my early mistakes have come back to haunt me.

I think it may have something to do with a very old down-voted post from when I first joined Stack Overflow. Can a Moderator undelete them so I can try and fix them too?

Comment: oh. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/86997

Comment: @nicael What is the link to? it just links me to hot topics

Comment: Here's a tip:  "I have tried using this code but i cant get it working." Is a pretty worthless statement you should avoid.  In your questions, identify what happens, and what you wanted to happen.  Also, include information gathered while debugging.  And if you're not debugging first, debug first.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should i rewrite them again?

You shouldn't rewrite them, not completely anyways - the original question should still be recognizable in the new form. What you should be doing is **improving** them - adding details, fixing typos, ensuring they are good questions (in general - following the [asking a good question guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)).

What you are hoping to achieve by all this is get upvotes on your posts. **That** is what will take you out of the question ban.

> Does anyone know what i should do now?

Are the questions now the best possible questions you could write? If so, you need to write answers. Good answers. Get those upvotes.

Frankly, that seems to be the problem - all these questions and only one has a positive score :(

Comment: I think i might be better off just deleting my account. How far under am i -100rep or so?

Comment: I don't see how you guys can make it to 85.7k

Comment: @Timothy Hmm... seeing as you have several other "user was removed" events in your profile, I'm starting to think you're trying to create fake accounts to upvote your posts in order to get free reputation. Don't do that; you'll be suspended. (Deleting your account won't help either; the question ban is at a lower level than account.)

Comment: @Doorknob" The question ban is at a lower level than account". You do realize that that's IP based.....

Comment: @Doorknob So basically i need to answer about 20 questions with a up-vote of 1 or more to get out?

Comment: @Timothy IP is lower level than account. Sure, you can fake your IP, but then you'll just keep getting suspended. I never said anything about answering x amount of questions with y amount of upvotes. The formula is secret, but if you improve your existing questions and perhaps post a few answers you can get out of it. What does that song have to do with anything?

Comment: I was just listening to it so i thought i would share it.

Comment: @Doorknob Of my question which ones are the worst and what should i do to fix them?

Comment: @Doorknob 3 of the questions i fixed just got up voted :)

Comment: I hope its not all from the same person.